# Cannot select elements inside "auto-binding" template

Tags: polymer

I have created some custom elements, now I'm writing tests for them.

I wanted to use ["auto-binding"](https://blog.polymer-project.org/howto/2014/09/11/template-is-autobinding/) because I have plenty of attributes that needs to be bound among my elements.

Unfortunately I cannot query any element inside the template.

Here is some code.

```
    <template id="root" is="auto-binding">
        <dalilak-data-service id="dds" regions="{{regions}}"></dalilak-data-service>

        <dalilak-regions-handler id="drh" regions="{{regions}}" flattendedRegions="{{flattendRegions}}" descendantsRegionNames="{{descendantsRegionNames}}" regionsByNameId="{{regionsByNameId}}"></dalilak-regions-handler>

    </template>
```

In the test script I have tried the following

```
   drh =  document.querySelector('#drh');
   suite('dalilak-regions-handler', function() {
        test('handler initialized', function() {
            assert.ok(drh);
        });
   });
```

Also tried this:

```
   drh =  document.querySelector('* /deep/ #drh');  // or '#root /deep/ #drh'     
   suite('dalilak-regions-handler', function() {
        test('handler initialized', function() {
            assert.ok(drh);
        });
   });
```

But none of them worked.

**Note** without the template I can query my custom elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto-binding` templates stamp asynchronously, I expect your problem is that you need to wait for the template to stamp before querying for elements.

The template fires a `template-bound` event when this happens, so you can use code like this:

```
addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
   drh =  document.querySelector('#drh');
   ...
});
```

Of course, this means your testing infrastructure will need to understand how to handle asynchrony, which can be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Where possible, it is best to avoid the /deep/ selector. That is a nuclear option and can return unexpected results because it pierces all shadow DOMs. It also won't work for your auto-binding template because its contents are inside a `#document-fragment`, not a `#shadow-root`. Instead, try querying the `#document-fragment` itself. This preferable because you are limiting your query to the scope of your template, which is much more precise.

```
var template = document.querySelector('#root');
var drh = template.content.querySelector('#drh');
```

Comment: A template is only a _stencil_ that describes how to create some DOM. The technique in this answer will only return the inert template elements. You really want the instance elements, which will be available in the document as normal, after the template stamps (which is asynchronous).